# Genetic Framework in Java

Tags: java, framework, optimization

I'm looking for an easy-to-use *Genetic Framework* in *Java*, which has to have the following features:

- Builtin multithreading support (possibly using *islands* and without the need to merge them manually, it will run on an 8-core server)
- Builtin integer chromosome (I need to work with integer arrays and I don't wat to write the chromosome code from scratch)
- Good amount of tutorials (Javadoc is not enough)
- Ability to serialize, pause (or shutdown) and restart the computation from the saved point (the *JGAP* sample code for serialization fails with an exception during loading)

The goal is to build a software that optimizes an array of `int` for a given function (which I already built), and since the array is 128 elements long I need it to work with multiple threads to speed things up.

For now I'm using *JGAP* which seems to be the best choice, but unfortunately the tutorials are quite "weak" if your goal goes beyond the contents of the *Getting Started* section. It is easy to use tho, since I didn't have to deal with writing code for *crossover* or *chromosome* but I could use the builtin types.

EDIT -

Just to clarify, by *easy-to-use* I mean something which allows me to start without having to manually write chromosomes, genetic operators or natural selector, so something packaged with basic types and operations. I need to write the less amount of code possible, basically I'd only like to write the evaluation function and plug it to the framework.